# Reading in char from file into struct

Tags: c, file-io, struct

For my assignment, I have to read in a text file with a varying amount of lines. They follow the following format:

```
AACTGGTGCAGATACTGTTGA
3
AACTGGTGCAGATACTGCAGA
CAGTTTAGAG
CATCATCATCATCATCATCAT
```

The first line is the original line I will testing the following ones against, with the second line giving the number of remaining lines.

I'm having trouble trying to save these to a struct, and can't even get the first line to save. I tried using the void function with an array and it seems to work, but can't seem to transfer it over to structs.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 25
struct dna {
    char code[LENGTH];
};
int main(){
    char filename[] = "input1.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen("input1.txt","r");

    char firstDna[LENGTH]="";

    struct dna first;
    struct dna first.code[]= "";

    makeArray(input,first);

//  printf("%s",filename);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void makeArray(FILE *input,struct dna first){
    int i=-1;
    //nested for loops to initialze array
    //from file
    while(i != '\n'){
       fscanf(input,"%c",first[i].code); 
       printf("%c", first[i].code);
       i++;
    }//closing file
    fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a struct? It would make more sense in this case to just store it in a char array. There are other issues with your code as well, but let's start with this.

Comment: Only reason is for extra credit and I'd like to try and get a grasp on it, but other than that, char array would work! @PandaConda

Comment: First, this will not be able to complete the compiler successfully.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I know, I'm just getting completely confused with it all.

Comment: The actual fragment size seems very small at `24` bases. Is this limitation part of the assignment. Is the `struct dna` specified in tha assignment?

Comment: @chqrlie no, it wasn't specified, just a rough guess based on the general length of "DNA string segments" given in the examples to the problem.

Comment: I don't know how advanced you are supposed to be in C, but if you know how to do that, you should not make any assumptions on maximum dna fragment lengths.

Comment: @chqrlie This is my first class using `c`, how would you suggest setting the length the best way? I'm by no means married to the number, just picked a random one...

Comment: reallocating the arrays is beyond your level, just pick some larger values: at least 128 bytes for the fragment lengths and at least room for 64 fragments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75427/discussion-between-bravesaint-and-chqrlie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for a class assignment, I want to preface this by saying that a good way to tackle these types of assignments is to break it up into tasks, then implement them one by one and finally connect them. In this case the tasks might be something like:

- parse the first line into a (struct containing a) char array.
- parse the number into an int variable
- parse each remaining line in the file like you did with the first line
- test the first line against the other lines in the file (except the number)

You also mentioned in a comment that the struct is for extra credit. For that reason, I'd recommend implementing it using just a char array first, then refactoring it into a struct once you have the basic version working. That way you have something to fall back on just in case. This way of developing might seem unnecessary at this point, but for larger more complicated projects it becomes a lot more important, so it's a really good habit to get into as early as possible.

Now, let's look at the code. I'm not going to give you the program here, but I'm going to identify the issues I see in it.

Let's start with the main method:

```
char filename[] = "input1.txt";
FILE *input = fopen("input1.txt","r");
```

This opens the file you're reading from. You're opening it correctly, but the first line is in this case unnecessary, since you never actually use the filename variable anywhere.

You also correctly close the file at the end of the `makeArray` function with the line:

```
fclose(input);
```

Which works. It would, however, probably be better style if you put this in the `main` method after calling the `makeArray` function. It's always a good idea to open and close files in the same function if possible, since this means you will always know you didn't forget to close the file without having to look through your entire program. Again, not really an issue in a small project, but a good habit to get into. Another solution would be to put the `fopen` and `fclose` functions in the `makeArray` function, so `main` doesn't have to know about them, then just send the `char` array containing the filepath to `makeArray` instead of the `FILE*`.

The next issue I see is with how you are passing the parameters to the `makeArray` function. To start off, instead of having a separate function, try putting everything in the main method. Using functions is good practice, but do this just to get something working.

Once that's done, something you need to be aware of is that if you're passing or returning arrays or pointers to/from functions, you will need to look up the `malloc` and `free` functions, which you may not have covered yet. This can be one of the more complex parts of C, so you might want to save this for last.

Some other things. I won't go into detail about these but try to get the concepts and not just copy paste:

- `struct dna first.code[]= "";` should probably be `first.code[0] = \0;`. `\0` is used in C to terminate strings, so this will make the string empty.
- Passing `%c` to `fscanf` reads a single character (you can also use `fgetc` for this). In this case, it will probably be easier using `%s`, which will return a word as a string.
- Assuming you do use `%s`, which you probably should, you will need to call it twice before the loop - once to get the first DNA sequence and another time to get the number of other DNA sequences (the number of iterations).
- Each iteration of the loop will then test the original DNA sequence against the next DNA sequence in the file.

I hope that helps!

Comment: `first.code = ""` would not work.  `*first.code = '\0'` or  `first.code[0] = '\0'` would.

Comment: `fscanf()` does not read line by line, it reads one char at a time in the OP's code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! The saving the file name as a char is used for later in the assignment, I just haven't gotten to formalizing the printf statement along with all the other stuff, yet. How would I go about calling the `fscanf` the second time to get the actual number of remaining lines? I realize how I could save that as a variable and use it within a different loop to save in the remaining lines, but am unsure of how it get it to process just the second line. Would my `while` loop found in the function work for getting the first line as it is? Thanks again! @PandaConda

Comment: @chqrlie: wouldn't it? I thought "strings" automatically got a `\0` added at the end? so `"hello"` would be stored as `['h','e','l','l','o','/0']`? As for your second comment, you're right. I'll edit this.

Comment: `first.code` is an array, you cannot set it with `first.code = "";`.  You could conceivably write `strcpy(first.code, "");` but a simpler way is to just set the first byte to `'\0'`.

Comment: @PandaConda would you mind helping me with calling the `fscanf function to only read in the second line??

Comment: @bravesaint: `fscanf(input, "%s", first.code);` will read a word from input and copy it into first.code. Use `%d` to to the same thing with digits (ints).

Comment: @chqrlie: You're probably right. I forgot there were some weird rules with converting between `char*` and `char[]`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @PandaConda, so if I used the `fscan` with `%s` to get the first line, then `fscanf` with %d to get the second line, following that up with a looped `fscanf %s`, that should differentiate between the lines? Basically, calling it the second time but with %d won't start from the beginning and just read the ASCI codes or whatever? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @bravesaint: You got it :P

Comment: @bravesaint: anytime! :)

Answer (score 1):

sample to fix

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 25

struct dna {
    char code[LENGTH];
};

struct dna *makeArray(FILE *input, int *n);//n : output, number of elements

int main(void){
    char filename[] = "input1.txt";
    FILE *input = fopen(filename,"r");

    struct dna first = { "" };
    fscanf(input, "%24s", first.code);//read first line
    printf("1st : %s\n", first.code);

    int i, size;
    struct dna *data = makeArray(input, &size);//this does close file

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        printf("%3d : %s\n", i+1, data[i].code);
    }
    free(data);//release data

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

struct dna *makeArray(FILE *input, int *n){//n : output, number of elements
    int i;

    fscanf(input, "%d", n);//read "number of remaining lines"

    struct dna *arr = calloc(*n, sizeof(struct dna));//like as struct dna arr[n] = {{0}};

    for(i = 0; i < *n; ++i){
        fscanf(input, "%24s", arr[i].code);
    }
    fclose(input);

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work perfectly. I am just overwhelmed trying to read it as I can't quite follow what is going on in certain parts. Such as: 'struct dna *data' - where is this getting saved? Is this a new struct altogether? 'fscanf(input, "%d", n)' is simply reading the second line of the text file and saving it as "n", correct? I also have no idea what 'calloc(*n, sizeof(struct dna))' does?! Thank you so much though!

Comment: While this is a solution, I think for a question like this it would be useful to explain the concepts a bit. For example, I doubt bravesaint will have previously covered things like `%24s`, referencing and dereferencing, or `calloc`/`free`.

Comment: Closing the file in `makeArray()` is very bad style.  You should also test whether you can actually read `size` fragments.

Comment: 1) `struct dna *data`  receive return of `makeArray`. `makeArray` is memory area allocate at heap.

Comment: 2) `fscanf(input, "%d", n)'` : `n` is pointer from passed by `&size` at main .

Comment: 3) `calloc(*n, sizeof(struct dna))` : calloc(number of element, size of element)  secure the area of the (number of element)*(size of element) and initialize to 0. read reference.

Comment: Since you do not test the return value of `fscanf(input, "%d", n)`, `calloc(*n, sizeof(struct dna))` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chqrlie To check the return value of the function is a basic.(E.g add `fopen`). And to present the basic sample is omitted since it is not going to provide as complete purposes.

Answer (score 1):

a simple fix might be :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 25

struct dna {
    char code[LENGTH];
};

void makeArray(FILE *input,struct dna *first){
    int i=0;
    fscanf(input,"%c",&first->code[i]);
    printf("%c",first->code[i]);
    while(first->code[i] != '\n' && i < LENGTH){
        i++;
        fscanf(input,"%c",&first->code[i]);
        printf("%c",first->code[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct dna first;
    char filename[] = "input1.txt";
    FILE *input     = fopen(filename,"r");
    makeArray(input,&first);
    fclose(input);
    printf("%s",first.code);
    return 0;
}
```

PS: i tried to not change your original code
in order to change the code[Length] in the makeArray function you will have to pass it's adresse this is why i call mkaeArray function this way : `makeArray(input,&first);`.